# App resource usage over time

Tags: applications, 6.0-marshmallow, resource-monitoring

Looking for a way to collect resource usage (processor, at least) on unrooted OS for running apps over time. This last part is crucial, since there are *numerous* apps presenting *current* usage for running applications, but i’m yet to find one which can generate statistics, collected by running in the background, for used apps over a period of time. Basically my question is a duplicate of [this one](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/27555/how-to-log-and-visualize-resource-usage-stats-to-identify-resource-hogs), but it was last active in 2012 and also never really got an answer for realtime statistics collection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the developer of [3C Toolbox Pro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ccc71.at.free) in [XDA](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=82878961&postcount=1199)

> - [3C Task Recorder](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ccc71.tr), whether rooted or not, it can collect CPU, memory and network usage . It creates a CSV file that you can easily use from a PC.

> - If non rooted, you will need [3C Companion PC app](https://3c71.com/android/?q=node/2769)
>   to enable memory usage and improved CPU stats.

- Recording options in screen shots below (some of them paid)

[image]
[image]

- I don't use the recorder. The pro version of Toolbox linked at top is far more versatile and has tons of features (there is a free version too with less features). If you are interested only in usage, the recorder should suffice. Screenshots from 3C Toolbox

[image]
[image]

**Edit**

OP confirms

> Task Recorder works great and could actually unrootedly track random access memory usage for me even without its companion.

Comment: Well said, and thank you for this input. «Task Recorder» works great and could actually unrootedly track random access memory usage for me even without its companion. Accepting your answer!